# Automating the use of external config files in Grails

Tags: grails, config

I am doing what appears to be the best practices for using an external config file in Grails.

```
grails.config.locations = ["classpath:${appName}-config.groovy",
                           "file:./${appName}-config.groovy"]
if (System.properties["${appName}.config.location"]) {
   grails.config.locations << "file:" + System.properties["${appName}.config.location"]
}
```

I put the config file in the root folder during testing and it works. And I manually put the config file in our Tomcat server's lib folder (in the classpath) during production and it worked. But I don't want to have to copy/create our external config file every time. After building a war and deploying an app, is it possible for my config file to be moved to the correct location so that I don't have to manually move it during deployment of any of my apps? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I would edit the title of the question to reflect your actual problem which is about automation.

It depends on how **manual** your existing process is...

Let's imagine the following:

- You have a continuous integration engine such as Jenkins/Hudson running
- You *scp/rsync* the external configuration file upon successful builds
- You deploy the application to the server upon successful builds (assuming a gant deploy script under *projectName/scripts* -> *Tomcat, JBoss, Websphere, etc*.)

Answer (score 0):

In out project we need to provide different configuration settings per environment (local, development, testing, production). While we want to avoid the hassle of updating config files on the different servers themselves, we do need to allow quick overriding of config values on a specific environment.

To accomodate these requirements we have the following setup of 'cascading' configuration files:

- common.properties bundled in the .war file and is always loaded
- xxx.properties files are bundled in the .war file, and depending on the value of an environment variable (appEnv) one or none of these configuration files is loaded (e.g. if the environment variable is yyy, yyy.properties is loaded)
- configuration files on the local file system are found using the appEnv and appLibRoot environment variables. If a configuration file corresponding to appEnv.properties is found, it is loaded last.

Loading the config files on startp of the Grail application is done by simply providing a list of configuration file locations in Config.groovy. The AppEnv class creates the list of configuration files using the appEnv and appLibRoot environment variables, and checking which files actually exist in the classpath and on the file system.

```
Config.groovy    
grails.config.locations = AppEnv.instance.configLocations
```